# How can I create a reactive string based on some form values in different components?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am uncertain how to set up my service and sibling components to pass formcontrol values. I need to pass certain values between the components because there is a string I need to form based on values in the form.

So componentA and componentB are sibling components making up parts of my form.

componentA has fields date, title, and user. 
componentB has fields grade, state, plan,

All of the formcontrols are part of a formgroup in their respective *.ts

I am using Angular 8 and Material. I know I need to use my dataservice.ts to create a function that the sibling components can utilize.

However I am pretty new to this and cannot figure out how to pass a JSON in the BeahviorSubject. I need a JSON object I figure since I need to be able to retain the positions of each of the values in the string to be generated.

In componentA I need to generate a string with the value:
"title.value - user.value - date.value - grade.value - state.value - plan.value"

Answer (score 0):

try this: Make a service. and inside of the service create the form and keep it in a propety. inject the service in all components and make a method in the service that return the value what u want. and in each component u can do `this.myService.form` and get the same form in all components. This is possible because the services are Singletone in angular. when angular create the object of the service share it on all places that you need inject.